# Data type when returning multiple values

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following Python code:

```
def foo():
    return 2, 4, 6

y = foo()
print y
```

This tells me that `y` has the value `(2, 4, 6)`, with curved brackets. But this is not a `list`, othewise `y` would have the value `[2, 4, 6]`, with square brackets. So what is the data type of `y` called, and can it be used in exactly the same way as a `list`?

Comment: `print type(y)`, Google, problem solved.

Comment: `help(y)` gives you all kinds of information on all python objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you might be looking for!

After researching how to find the data-types of variables I've come across this:

```
>>> y = 2,4,6
(2,4,6)
>>> print (y.__class__)
<class 'tuple'>
```

A **tuple** is a data-type much like a list in that it stores seperate values, but it is indeed **not** a list.

Tuples are quite interesting to learn about! I would recommend looking here for more info: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_tuples.htm

Comment: "To explicitly remove an entire tuple, just use the del statement." Man, tutorialspoint is horrible.